# how to use IN operator in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to update multiple records in MySQL table but its not working only the first record is getting updated. I am using MySQL 'IN' for updating mutiple records.

My Code:

```
CALL  my_proc_name('','','','','','','','','','','','','','',$modifiedby,$modifiedon,'$status','$type','$ids','$start','$limit','$remarks');
```

My SP is:

```
UPDATE my_table_name SET modifiedby=modifiedby1,modifiedon=modifiedon1,status=status1 WHERE leaveid IN (id);
```

Parameters are:

```
$ids = 2016,2017,2019,2020
$status = 'Approved'
```

My problem here is only the first record is getting updated, in this case as per my above parameters only id 2016 is updated. What is my mistake here? My question here is can I give opening ('(') & closing (')') braces directly for my table column 'id' like "IN (id)" to stored procedure?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844290/using-mysql-variable-to-hold-comma-separated-value-to-be-used-for-where-in-claus

Comment: I tried but no luck, I am writing mysql SP in a different way compared to your given example, I am using PHPMyAdmin's "Add/Edit Routine" popup window to create/edit the Stored procedures.

Comment: I guess mysql is seeing ids as string and is finding 2016 because of the implict string to integer behaviour of mysql. If first element was 2017 then it will probably find 2017. To test all elements individually you should try something similar to the 3rd approach in the link provided by vatev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. **"FIND_IN_SET" has solved my problem**, but the row id's which I update must be declared as "varchar" in my Stored Procedure(SP) here that is my column 'id' should be "varchar" in SP.

Below is my modified SP:

```
UPDATE my_table_name SET modifiedby=modifiedby1,modifiedon=modifiedon1,status=status1 WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(leaveid,id);
```